# How do I pass a CollectionProperty from a Panel to an Operator sto create general classes for UIList

Tags: python, interface, panel

I want to put multiple UILists in my addon.  I started off with the example discussed here:
https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/using-uilists-in-blender/
I am storing each list in a scene custom property as a CollectionProperty, but I would like to have only one set of operators (LIST_OT_NewItem, for example) for all of my lists.  To do this, I would need to pass the list and other parameters from the panel to the operator.

The code I am working on can pass one parameter, such at the index or the item to add to the list, but I am having trouble passing the list itself.  Here is my code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import StringProperty, BoolProperty, PointerProperty, IntProperty, CollectionProperty, EnumProperty, FloatProperty, FloatVectorProperty
from bpy.types import Operator,PropertyGroup

class CustomListItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name: bpy.props.StringProperty()     

class LIST_OT_NewItem(Operator): 
    """Add a new item to the list."""
    bl_idname = "my_list.new_item" 
    bl_label = "Add a new item"

    item_list_name: StringProperty(name="item_list_name")
    item_list: CollectionProperty(type= CustomListItem)
    item_val: StringProperty(name="item_val",default="")

    def execute(self, context):
#        item-self.item_list.add()
        item=eval(self.item_list_name+".add()")
#        item=context.scene.theList.add()
#        item.name = str(context.scene.list_item)
        item.name = str(self.item_val)
        return{'FINISHED'} 

class LIST_OT_DeleteListItem(Operator): 
    """Delete the selected item from the list."""
    bl_idname = "my_list.delete_list_item"
    bl_label = "Deletes an item"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.scene.theList

    item_index: IntProperty(name="item_index")

    def execute(self, context):
        the_list = context.scene.theList
        index = self.item_index
        the_list.remove(index)
        self.item_index = min(max(0, index - 1), len(the_list) - 1)
        print('delete: ',index,self.item_index)
        return{'FINISHED'}
    
class OBJECT_UL_List(bpy.types.UIList):

    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname):
        scene = data
        ob = item
        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:
            layout.prop(ob, "name", text="", emboss=False, icon_value=layout.icon(ob))
            
class SCENE_PT_TestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "UIList Test"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_test_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        obj=context.active_object
        split=layout.split()
        col = split.column()
        col.label(text="List 1")
        col.template_list("OBJECT_UL_List", "",scene,"theList",scene,"list_index")
        col.operator('my_list.delete_list_item', text='Remove').item_index=scene.list_index
        row=col.row()
        op=row.operator('my_list.new_item', text='Add').item_val=scene.list_item
        op.item_list_name="context.scene.theList"
        row.prop(scene, "list_item")

        col = split.column()
        col.label(text="place holder")
        row=col.row()
        col.label(text="for second list")

classes = (CustomListItem,OBJECT_UL_List,LIST_OT_NewItem,SCENE_PT_TestPanel,LIST_OT_DeleteListItem)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.theList = CollectionProperty(type = CustomListItem)
    bpy.types.Scene.list_index = IntProperty(name = "List index", default = 0)
    bpy.types.Scene.list_item = StringProperty(name="list_item",default="1.0")

def unregister():
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.theList 
    del bpy.types.Scene.list_index
    del bpy.types.Scene.list_item 
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

In this code, I am trying to send the LIST_OT_NewItem operator the list and the item that will be added to it.  I was having trouble passing the list to the operator, so I decided to try passing the name of the list, as shown in the code above.  This code give me the follow error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'item_list_name' when I press the add button for the line related to that variable in the TestPanel class.

It is possible to write one general operator to add an item to any list instead of writing a separate operator for each UIList?

Comment: You can make a function to create classes.